# How to remove duplicate records in azure synapse serverless?

Tags: azure-synapse

I have written an SQL script to place the data I've received, in the serverless pool. I did this through the CETAS method (or process) which is Create External Table As Select. This data does show up in my application however I've noticed there are duplicate records in my data, which I want to remove.

I want to remove these values before it gets to my data application therefore in Synapse. I want to remove all duplicate records, each row is unique to the other. Because of the limitations of CETAS, I have no idea how to go on about this.

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove duplicate records in azure synapse serverless?

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-as-select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=powershell)

> - Data manipulation language (DML) operations aren't supported on external tables. For example, you can't use the Transact-SQL update, insert, or delete Transact-SQL statements to modify the external data.
> - CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, CREATE STATISTICS, DROP STATISTICS, CREATE VIEW, and DROP VIEW are the only data definition language (DDL) operations allowed on external tables.

Since DML operations are not directly supported on external tables in serverless SQL pools, and `CREATE TABLE` is not allowed.

The possible workaround can be creating a view based on that external table and use it in your application as you can't use DML operation on both External table and view.

**SQL code for the same:**

```sql
CREATE  VIEW [dbo].[View2]
AS  SELECT  DISTINCT * FROM [demoext1] --external table created by CETAS
```